# Bootstrap 3 side-nav with many items won't scroll in full page view

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the Bootstrap sb-admin v2 template. I am making use of the side-nav bar. I seem to be having the opposite problem of everyone else out there... When viewing the page on a desktop monitor, if I expand the  dropdowns for the

items or add enough top level

items such that the  contents extend beyond the viewport's height, they are cut off and will not scroll. When I resize the window or look at the page on any mobile device, the menu collapses as expected, and I can scroll through the nav

items. I have tried many things using overflow-y: auto, scroll, etc... on all related css classes and nothing seems to work. I have tried javascript fixes, but that breaks the mobile functionality. It's all straight out of the bootstrap.min.css file for version 3.3 I'm at a loss as to how to fix this. Any suggestions?

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
  <ul id="sideMenu" class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
    <li><a id="menuItem" href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#NewsItems"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-newspaper-o"></i> News Items <i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i></a>
      <ul id="NewsItems" class="collapse">
        <li><a runat="server" href="/admin/modules/news-items/view.aspx">Manage</a>
        </li>
        <li><a runat="server" href="/admin/modules/news-items/add.aspx">Add</a>
        </li>
        <li><a runat="server" href="/admin/modules/categories/view.aspx?CategoryType=NewsItem">Manage Categories</a>
        </li>
        <li><a runat="server" href="/admin/modules/categories/add.aspx?CategoryType=NewsItem">Add Category</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Photos"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-camera"></i> Photos <i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i></a>
      <ul id="Photos" class="collapse">
        <li><a runat="server" href="/admin/modules/photos/view.aspx">Manage</a>
        </li>
        <li><a runat="server" href="/admin/modules/photos/add.aspx">Add</a>
        </li>
        <li><a runat="server" href="/admin/modules/categories/view.aspx?CategoryType=Photo">Manage Categories</a>
        </li>
        <li><a runat="server" href="/admin/modules/categories/add.aspx?CategoryType=Photo">Add Category</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Blogs"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-rss"></i> Blogs <i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i></a>
      <ul id="Blogs" class="collapse">
        <li><a runat="server" href="/admin/modules/blogs/view.aspx">Manage</a>
        </li>
        <li><a runat="server" href="/admin/modules/blogs/add.aspx">Add</a>
        </li>
        <li><a runat="server" href="/admin/modules/categories/view.aspx?CategoryType=Blog">Manage Categories</a>
        </li>
        <li><a runat="server" href="/admin/modules/categories/add.aspx?CategoryType=Blog">Add Category</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Albums"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-photo"></i> Albums <i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i></a>
      <ul id="Albums" class="collapse">
        <li><a runat="server" href="/admin/modules/albums/view.aspx">Manage</a>
        </li>
        <li><a runat="server" href="/admin/modules/albums/add.aspx">Add</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Audio"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-music"></i> Audio <i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i></a>
      <ul id="Audio" class="collapse">
        <li><a runat="server" href="/admin/modules/audio/view.aspx">Manage</a>
        </li>
        <li><a runat="server" href="/admin/modules/audio/add.aspx">Add</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Events"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-calendar-o"></i> Events <i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i></a>
      <ul id="Events" class="collapse">
        <li><a runat="server" href="/admin/modules/events/view.aspx">Manage</a>
        </li>
        <li><a runat="server" href="/admin/modules/events/add.aspx">Add</a>
        </li>
        <li><a runat="server" href="/admin/modules/categories/view.aspx?CategoryType=Event">Manage Categories</a>
        </li>
        <li><a runat="server" href="/admin/modules/categories/add.aspx?CategoryType=Event">Add Category</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#MenuItems"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-navicon"></i> Menu Items <i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i></a>
      <ul id="MenuItems" class="collapse">
        <li><a runat="server" href="/admin/modules/menu-items/view.aspx">Manage</a>
        </li>
        <li><a runat="server" href="/admin/modules/menu-items/add.aspx">Add</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Pages"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-file-o"></i> Pages <i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i></a>
      <ul id="Pages" class="collapse">
        <li><a runat="server" href="/admin/modules/pages/view.aspx">Manage</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Roles"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-users"></i> Roles <i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i></a>
      <ul id="Roles" class="collapse">
        <li><a runat="server" href="/admin/modules/roles/view.aspx">Manage</a>
        </li>
        <li><a runat="server" href="/admin/modules/roles/add.aspx">Add</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Users"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> Users <i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i></a>
      <ul id="Users" class="collapse">
        <li><a runat="server" href="/admin/modules/users/view.aspx">Manage</a>
        </li>
        <li><a runat="server" href="/admin/modules/users/add.aspx">Add</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It's kinda hard to figure out without having an actual demo. Can you make a Codepen or something? The easiest way to track the problem is by using the Google inspector Element's tab and check the css on the different elements.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to fix this for days.... Minutes after posting this question I found the answer...

All I needed to do was add height: 100%; to the side-nav div in the sb-admin.css file as follows:

```css
@media(min-width:768px) {
  .side-nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 51px;
    left: 225px;
    width: 225px;
    margin-left: -225px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: #222;
    height: 100%;
  }
```